# Creating JSON Web Tokens through Basic Authentication endpoint? Dropwizard

Tags: java, jwt, dropwizard

Using Dropwizard 1.2.0 and [Dropwizard JWT library](https://github.com/dhatim/dropwizard-jwt-cookie-authentication), I am trying to create json web tokens from an API endpoint called `/token`

This endpoint requires the client to pass a username and password, using Basic Authentication method. If successful the response will contain a JSON web token.

**Principal**

```
public class ShepherdAuth implements JwtCookiePrincipal {

private String name;
private Set<String> roles;

public ShepherdAuth(String name, Set<String> roles) {
    this.name = checkNotNull(name, "User name is required");
    this.roles = checkNotNull(roles, "Roles are required");
}

@Override
public boolean isPersistent() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isInRole(final String s) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

@Override
public boolean implies(Subject subject) {
    return false;
}

public Set<String> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
}
```

**Authenticator**

```
public class ShepherdAuthenticator implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, ShepherdAuth> {

private static final Map<String, Set<String>> VALID_USERS = ImmutableMap.of(
        "guest", ImmutableSet.of(),
        "shepherd", ImmutableSet.of("SHEPHERD"),
        "admin", ImmutableSet.of("ADMIN", "SHEPHERD")
);

@Override
public Optional<ShepherdAuth> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (VALID_USERS.containsKey(credentials.getUsername()) && "password".equals(credentials.getPassword())) {
        return Optional.of(new ShepherdAuth(credentials.getUsername(), VALID_USERS.get(credentials.getUsername())));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
}
```

**Resource / Controller**

```
public class ShepherdController implements ShepherdApi {

public ShepherdController() {
}

@PermitAll
@GET
@Path("/token")
public ShepherdAuth auth(@Auth final BasicCredentials user) {
    return new ShepherdAuth(user.getUsername(),
        ImmutableSet.of("SHEPHERD"));
}
```

**App / Config**

```
    @Override
public void run(final ShepherdServiceConfiguration configuration,
                final Environment environment) {

    final ShepherdController shepherdController = new ShepherdController();

    // app authentication
    environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<ShepherdAuth>()
            .setAuthenticator(new ShepherdAuthenticator())
            .setAuthorizer(new ShepherdAuthorizer())
            .setRealm(configuration.getName())
            .buildAuthFilter()));
```

When I try to make a request to `/shepherd/token` I do not get a prompt for basic auth, instead I get a HTTP 401 response with

> Credentials are required to access this resource.

How do I get the controller to prompt for username and password and generate a JWT on success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented JWT tokens in my project by using https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt but the solution will easily be applied to another library. The trick is to use different authenticators.

This answer is not suited for [Dropwizard JWT Library](https://github.com/dhatim/dropwizard-jwt-cookie-authentication) but does the fine job of providing JWT for Dropwizard :)

First, the application:

```
environment.jersey().register(new TokenResource(configuration.getJwsSecretKey()));
environment.jersey().register(new HelloResource());
environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
environment.jersey()
    .register(
        new AuthDynamicFeature(
            new ChainedAuthFilter<>(
                Arrays
                    .asList(
                        new JWTCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
                            .setAuthenticator(
                                new JWTAuthenticator(configuration.getJwsSecretKey()))
                            .setPrefix("Bearer").setAuthorizer(new UserAuthorizer())
                            .buildAuthFilter(),
                        new JWTDefaultCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
                            .setAuthenticator(new JWTDefaultAuthenticator())
                            .setAuthorizer(new UserAuthorizer()).setRealm("SUPER SECRET STUFF")
                            .buildAuthFilter()))));
```

Please note that the configuration class must contain a configuration setting:

```
String jwsSecretKey;
```

Here, the `TokenResource` is the token supplying resource, and the `HelloResource` is our test resource. `User` is the principal, like this:

```
public class User implements Principal {
  private String name;
  private String password;
  ...
}
```

And there is one class for communicating the JWT token:

```
public class JWTCredentials {
  private String jwtToken;
  ...
}
```

`TokenResource` provides tokens for a user "test" with password "test":

```
@POST
@Path("{user}")
@PermitAll
public String createToken(@PathParam("user") String user, String password) {
  if ("test".equals(user) && "test".equals(password)) {
    SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;
    long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date now = new Date(nowMillis);
    byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(this.secretKey);
    Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());
    JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setIssuedAt(now).setSubject("test")
      .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey);
    return builder.compact();
  }
  throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

And the `HelloResource` just echoes back the user:

```
@GET
@RolesAllowed({"ANY"})
public String hello(@Auth User user) {
  return "hello user \"" + user.getName() + "\"";
}
```

`JWTCredentialAuthFilter` provides credentials for both authentication schemes:

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class JWTCredentialAuthFilter<P extends Principal> extends AuthFilter<JWTCredentials, P> {

  public static class Builder<P extends Principal>
      extends AuthFilterBuilder<JWTCredentials, P, JWTCredentialAuthFilter<P>> {

    @Override
    protected JWTCredentialAuthFilter<P> newInstance() {
      return new JWTCredentialAuthFilter<>();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    final JWTCredentials credentials =
    getCredentials(requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
    if (!authenticate(requestContext, credentials, "JWT")) {
      throw new WebApplicationException(
          this.unauthorizedHandler.buildResponse(this.prefix, this.realm));
    }
  }

  private static JWTCredentials getCredentials(String authLine) {
    if (authLine != null && authLine.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      JWTCredentials result = new JWTCredentials();
      result.setJwtToken(authLine.substring(7));
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

`JWTAuthenticator` is when JWT credentials are provided:

```
public class JWTAuthenticator implements Authenticator<JWTCredentials, User> {

  private String secret;

  public JWTAuthenticator(String jwtsecret) {
    this.secret = jwtsecret;
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<User> authenticate(JWTCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
      Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(this.secret))
      .parseClaimsJws(credentials.getJwtToken()).getBody();
      User user = new User();
      user.setName(claims.getSubject());
      return Optional.ofNullable(user);
    } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") ExpiredJwtException | UnsupportedJwtException
        | MalformedJwtException | SignatureException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
  }
}
```

`JWTDefaultAuthenticator` is when no credentials are present, giving the code an empty user:

```
public class JWTDefaultAuthenticator implements Authenticator<JWTCredentials, User> {

  @Override
  public Optional<User> authenticate(JWTCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
    return Optional.of(new User());
  }
}
```

`UserAuthorizer` permits the "ANY" role, as long as the user is not null:

```
public class UserAuthorizer implements Authorizer<User> {
  @Override
  public boolean authorize(User user, String role) {
    return user != null && "ANY".equals(role)
  }
}
```

If all goes well,

```
curl -s -X POST -d 'test' http://localhost:8080/token/test
```

will give you something like:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MDk3MDYwMjYsInN1YiI6InRlc3QifQ.ZrRmWTUDpaA6JlU4ysIcFllxtqvUS2OPbCMJgyou_tY
```

and this query

```
curl -s -X POST -d 'xtest' http://localhost:8080/token/test
```

will fail with

```
{"code":401,"message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}
```

(BTW, "test" in the URL is the user name and "test" in the post data is the password. As easy as basic auth, and can be configured for CORS.)

and the request

```
curl -s -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MDk3MDYwMjYsInN1YiI6InRlc3QifQ.ZrRmWTUDpaA6JlU4ysIcFllxtqvUS2OPbCMJgyou_tY' http://localhost:8080/hello
```

will show

```
hello user "test"
```

while

```
curl -s -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer invalid' http://localhost:8080/hello
```

and

```
curl -s -X GET http://localhost:8080/hello
```

will result in

```
{"code":403,"message":"User not authorized."}
```

Comment: Thanks but this library is not stable, it is only version 0.9.0 :(

Comment: Two things: Don't let the version mislead you, I know Dropwizard has been used for many different production environments before version 1. Second, Dropwizard JWT library uses the same library. Check the pom.xml of it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but it is saying it cannot find `JWTCredentials` class, do I have to make this or is it provided by another library?

Comment: My bad. Edited the answer to include it too. It's just a POJO with `jwtToken` property only.

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there anyway to use Basic Authentication with `TokenResource` instead of DefaultJWTAuthenticator?
I tried adding `BasicCredentialAuthFilter` to that list of authenticators but Dropwizard is not prompting for login when trying to use that endpoint to get a token.
Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I decided to use a login through the request body as JSON which I deserialize.

Comment: It is possible by changing JWTCredentialAuthFilter to check for the authentication headers also, but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 1):

Your missing this line in your configuration.

`environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));`